# Pass extra argument to auth url

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to implement google allauth authentication.

Before clicking this button to make google register a user:

`<a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}" type="submit">Registrarse with Google</a>`

I have this input field

`<input id="nombrelink" placeholder="specialname"></input>`

What that button does is automatically register and log the user in.

I would like to pass this input parameter to the google button so that whenever someone creates an account, that inputs gets prepended to their database

How can I pass an extra argument to that url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the parameter to the url using jQuery for example.

```js
$('#nombrelink').change(function(){
  var href = $('#provider-url').attr('href');
  //This is the new href attr
  var new_href = href +'?nombrelink='+ $(this).val();
  $('#provider-url').attr('href',new_href);  
  console.log($('#provider-url').attr('href'));
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="provider-url" href="/provider-login-url/google" type="submit">Registrarse con Google</a>
<input id="nombrelink" placeholder="specialname"></input>
```

Then in your view, you can access that parameter through request:

```
#inside your view
nombrelink = request.GET.get('nombrelink')
```